# How can I move several windows at once in FL Studio?

Tags: windows, fl-studio

How can I move several windows at once in FL Studio?

I tried to select several windows pressing either <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> but it didn't work.

I use FL Studio on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.